# how to using Optical Character Recognition (OCR) in react native that using expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm Trying to use OCR in react-native that using expo too.
I've tried using Tesseract but it has error, i've search the solution, and seems  i should eject the expo.
i want to use pure tesseract javascript, but expo doesn't support standar node.
is there any other way ? it could be better if you have some example on it. Thank You.

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@jesse/ocr-test

Comment: @hongdeveloper that doesn't work anymore.